# How do I compare two source trees in Linux?

Tags: diff

I have two directories containing source files to a project I've inherited with little by way of documentation. How do I compare both directories to make see what the differences are?

Comment: With all the right answers provided above, if you need any video help I found this useful video in my search for answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcJkLV1EeuU

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try [Meld](http://meld.sourceforge.net/). It is a wonderful visual diff tool ;-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch- I discovered Meld belated after having posted my question and it does pretty much what I want. It would be nice if I didn't have to download the code to my local machine though as its on a remote server and (unfortunately) not checked into like CVS or Subversion.

Comment: Meld lets you see the diffs in the tree structure as well as line-by-line diffs in files. In addition, you can selectively apply changes in one directory to the other. Magnificent!

Comment: I had actually used Meld for file comparisons already, but I was not aware it was this great for tree comparison.

Answer (score 60):

Try this:

```
diff -Naur dir1/ dir2/
```

- The `-u` option makes the output a
  little easier to read.
- The `-r` option recurses through all
  subdirectories
- The `-N` and `-a` options are really
  only necessary if you wanted to create
  a patch file.

Comment: As an human-readability enhancement to this, you can pipe to a tool like [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/) and get diff syntax highlighting:
```bash
diff -Nur dir1/ dir2/ | bat -l diff
```

Answer (score 29):

```
diff -u -r dirA dirB
```

Will show you a unified recursive diff between the files in dirA and dirB

Comment: This works in Cygwin as well, which was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 7):

You may use the diff command in the shell. Or install a tool like [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 for KDiff3.  Works a treat for comparing directories (and subdirectories etc.)

Comment: +1 - I'd looked at KDiff3 but hadn't realised it did it due to me using drag-and-drop.  You *can* drag-n-drop directories, but you'll need use the open dialog and hit OK for it to start the compare.

Answer (score 1):

The diff command to compare directories kept telling me that I didn't have differences, when I knew there were differences.

Instead of using diff directly, I used a sorted list of md5sums and then compared those files with diff:

```
find /path1/dir/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $2 $1}' | sort >! path1.log
find /path2/dir/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $2 $1}' | sort >! path2.log
gvimdiff path1.log path2.log
```

If the beginning part of the path is causing headaches, then change it. Select the Path1 window and type:

```
:%s|path1|path2|g
```

This will replace all instances of path1 with path2 in the first file, and now your diff should only show differences.

Comment: I've never seen `>!` before. What does it do?

Comment: I'm just going to assume the `>!` bit is a typo and that it should read `>`. That way the command and process makes sense.

Comment: +1 assuming the `>!` is changed to `>`; the other minor variation I did was simply change directory to `path1/dir` and do `find .` so I wouldn't have to manually change the pathnames

Comment: Actually the >! is a csh redirect that will overwrite existing files. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762348/what-do-and-do-in-tcsh

Comment: This seems to assume there are only two fields - ie, that filenames do not contain whitespace characters. Any work-arounds?

Comment: @TomHale I would use sed to deal with spaces in paths:
`find /path1/dir/ -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sed 's/\([^\ ]\+ \)\(.*\)/\2 \1/' | sort >! path1.log`
The `sed` command is looking for a string with no spaces, and then it puts that string at the end, ignoring all other spaces.