# What do >! and >>! do in tcsh

Tags: redirect, tcsh

In normal bash redirection `>` redirecting standard output to a file, overwriting when it exists and `>>` redirecting standard output to a file, appending when it exists.

In a tcsh (c shell) script I found the operators `>!` `>>!` being used. What do this operators do? tcsh does also have the `>` and `>>` operators, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In tcsh redirection the ! symbol means overwrite the existing file even if `noclobber` is set.

In other words, if noclobber is set then:

- `cmd > file` will write `stdout` to *file* if *file* does not exist
- `cmd > file` will fail if *file* exists
- `cmd >> file` will append `stdout` to *file* if *file* exists
- `cmd >> file` will fail if *file* does not exist
- `cmd >! file` will write `stdout` to *file*, overwriting any existing file
- `cmd >>! file` will append `stdout` to *file*, creating the file if it does not already exist

If `noclobber` is **not** set then the ! has no effect:

- `cmd > file` will write `stdout` to *file*, overwriting any existing file
- `cmd >> file` will append `stdout` to *file*
- `cmd >! file` will write `stdout` to *file*, overwriting any existing file
- `cmd >>! file` will append `stdout` to *file*

Comment: Note that bash has something similar.  It has its own "noclobber" option (which is typically not set), and uses ">|" and ">>|" to override it.

Answer (score 4):

The exclamation mark suppresses the check for the type of file being written to in certain cases.

To quote the tcsh man page:

> If  the  shell  variable noclobber is set, then the file must not exist or be a character special file (e.g., a terminal or ‘/dev/null’) or an error results.  This helps prevent accidental  destruction  of files.  In this case the ‘!’ forms can be used to suppress this check.