# How to send output of Perforce sync command to text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, perforce

I've got the following Perforce command in a bat file:

```
p4 -c myworkspace sync //path/...
```

and I want to re-direct the output to a file. I tried:

```
p4 -c myworkspace sync //path/... >> file.txt
```

but the output is show in the command line and doesn't appear in the file. How to solve this?

Is there a parameter I can send to perforce to write the output to a file or can I do this directly from the bat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be writing to the `STDERR` stream so this could help.

```
p4 -c myworkspace sync //path/... >>file.txt 2>&1
```

`>>file.txt` will append to file.txt and `>file.txt` will create a new file every time.

Comment: That worked, I saw this solution before but disregarded it because I was certain it didn't write to the error stream - weird it does that.

Answer (score 1):

[foxidrive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2299431/foxidrive)'s answer pertains only to bash.

For (t)csh, `STDERR` stream redirection is [different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35715/stderr-redirection-not-working-in-csh), use

```
p4 -c myworkspace sync //path/... >> & file.txt
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6762399) for more redirection options.