# What does ">!" do in bash or nawk?

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I am translating a GAWK script into a C# program and I don't know what part of the GAWK script means.  I've got the rest of the script figured out but I can't seem to find where to look for the rest of these commands.

I don't have an example of the other .tg files that its reading so I'm copying it blind and I need to get it right.

These are the lines:

```
date +"Report prepared %a %b %e %T %Y" >! $XTRAFILE
set ntg=`awk '\!/^#/{if(NF)print}' *.tg ad_tgs | wc -l`
```

Questions:

1. Am I right in assuming that it puts the ">!" puts the "Report prepared" at the top of the $XTRAFILE?
2. Also, I don't know what the "%a %b %e ..." is.
3. Finally, is the line starting with "set ntg" counting the lines in the ad_tgs file?

Comment: One question per question, please!

Comment: In the future, if you have questions about GAWK itself, I'd suggest using [Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gawk).

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6762399/2229272

Comment: I don't think that's Bash.

Comment: @Dragomok - why would you suggest that? Seems like a lot of awk or gawk questions get answered right here and if you really need experts then you should post in the comp.lang.awk newsgroup.

Comment: @jas Thanks for the link.  I searched for ">!" before I asked but nothing came up.

Comment: @EdMorton I meant no negative intent - just that Unix SE *might* have a bigger crowd of readily available answerers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. > Am I right in assuming that it puts the ">!" puts the "Report
   > prepared" at the top of the $XTRAFILE?

   `>!` came from `csh` and `tcsh`, will write `stdout` to file,
   overwriting any existing file

   [Read More Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311053900/http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html)
2. > Also, I don't know what the "%a %b %e ..." is.

   `%a`     locale's abbreviated weekday name (e.g., Sun)

   `%b`    locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)

   `%e`     day of month, space padded; same as %_d

   `%T`     time; same as %H:%M:%S

   `%Y`     year

   [Read more Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)
3. > Finally, is the line starting with "set ntg" counting the lines in the
   > ad_tgs file?

   ```
     set ntg=`awk '\!/^#/{if(NF)print}' *.tg ad_tgs | wc -l`
   ```

   Prints all records/rows, which does not start with char `#` and has
   at least 1 field from all files, whos extension is `.tg` and file
   `ad_tgs` and `| wc -l` count number of lines which awk printed, and
   finally store number of lines in variable `ntg`